# Negativar respostas por inconsistência, é válido?

Tags: debate

[Neste tópico](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/22310/1592), o usuário [Pedro Henrique](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/9013/pedro-henrique) postou uma resposta que na prática é *inconsistente* – talvez este não seja o melhor termo, mas estou em busca de algo melhor.

De acordo com o meu conhecimento e no problema apresentado, a solução que a resposta que o usuário Pedro propõe não faz jus ao que a pergunta precisa. Portanto, a negativei previamente – com justificativa – para dar destaque à informação incorreta que a resposta traz à tona.

Portanto, pergunto: essa minha conduta é coesa? Deveria eu esperar por um parecer do questionador para tomar partido com relação à resposta de Pedro?

#### Nota

Vejam, usei o termo "inconsistente" que não significa necessariamente incorreção. A resposta *pode* estar certa no contexto dela, mas não se encaixa à pergunta.

Comment: Guilherme, comece lendo [esta resposta do @Gabe](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1596/227). Leia as demais respostas também, pois o tópico trata justamente de caso de *downvote*.

Comment: @utluiz Obrigado pelo spotlight, não havia lido ele antes. Mas o que quero destacar é que a minha base/referência é técnica. Como eu disse, a resposta pode não estar errada em seu contexto, mas não corresponde ao problema apresentado – o que, na minha opinião, a torna inválida para a pergunta. É como eu perguntar sobre jogos de computador e você me responder sobre moléculas – o contexto técnico não está de acordo. Frisando, a sua resposta pode não estar errada, mas não coincide com o problema levantado.

Comment: Quando você passa o mouse na seta de baixo da resposta, aparece "Esta resposta não é útil". Evidentemente está falando que a resposta não é útil para aquele pergunta. Então tire sua conclusão.

Comment: @bigown Nunca reparei nisso. Faz sentido cara, obrigado.